# How do I show ruby images in Bootstrap Photoswipe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, photoswipe

This is a snippet of the original code for the gallery that shows the thumbnail then the same larger image in the light box.

`<a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">`

`<img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />`

I want to replace the url images with images pulled from my database in Rails usually expressed like this.

`<%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb), :class => 'img-thumbnailTest' %>`

I think the itemprop is key but I'm not sure how to combine it with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it as an option after `:class`

```
<%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb), :class => 'img-thumbnailTest', :itemprop => 'thumbnail' %>
```

The resulting HTML should look like the example.